# Does Python have something like anonymous inner classes of Java?

Tags: python, class, anonymous-class

In Java you can define a new class inline using anonymous inner classes. This is useful when you need to rewrite only a single method of the class.

Suppose that you want create a subclass of `OptionParser` that overrides only a single method (for example `exit()`). In Java you can write something like this:

```
new OptionParser () {

    public void exit() {
        // body of the method
    }
};
```

This piece of code creates a anonymous class that extends `OptionParser` and override only the `exit()` method.

There is a similar idiom in Python? Which idiom is used in these circumstances?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use the [`type(name, bases, dict)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type) builtin function to create classes on the fly.  For example:

```
op = type("MyOptionParser", (OptionParser,object), {"foo": lambda self: "foo" })
op().foo()
```

Since OptionParser isn't a new-style class, you have to explicitly include `object` in the list of base classes.

Comment: This is the **proper** way to inline class definitions/create anonymous classes (quote from the above cited manual page: "This is essentially a dynamic form of the class statement"); the "accepted answer" should point to it.

Comment: I don't understand this {"foo": lambda self: "foo" }. Is it supposed to be returning itself?

Comment: Click through on the link to the docs.  "the dict dictionary is the namespace containing definitions for class body and becomes the __dict__ attribute".  So "foo" is the name of a method that takes only "self" as a parameter.  That method happens to return the string "foo".

Comment: This is an example of a dynamic class, not anonymous.

Answer (score 16):

Java uses anonymous classes mostly to imitate closures or simply code blocks. Since in Python you can easily pass around methods there's no need for a construct as clunky as anonymous inner classes:

```
def printStuff():
   print "hello"

def doit(what):
   what()

doit(printStuff)
```

Edit: I'm aware that this is not what is needed in this special case. I just described the most common python solution to the problem most commonly by anonymous inner classes in Java.

Comment: -1 I want to subclass optparse.OptionParser() not pass around method references.

Comment: In that case what's the problem with writing a real subclass? I was merely illustrating the most common use of anonymous inner classes.

Comment: +1: Anonymous inner classes are a way for Java to lighten up on the complex syntax.  Python already has simple syntax and doesn't need anonymous classes to lighten up the load.

Comment: I known that Python is "better" but the answer is about passing method references while the question is about subclassing and overriding a single method.

Comment: I wouldn't say that Python is better. Every language has its strength. Passing around callable code is simply easier to do in Python than in Java. And I know that you are searching for something else, I keep my answer here in case someone else finds your question and is looking for what I provide.

Comment: @saua: That's right. I can't no more up vote, stackoverflow says that "This vote is too old to be undone or changed".

Answer (score 16):

You can accomplish this in three ways:

1. Proper subclass (of course)
2. a custom method that you invoke with the object as an argument
3. (what you probably want) -- adding a new method to an object (or replacing an existing one).

Example of option 3 (edited to remove use of "new" module -- It's deprecated, I did not know ):

```
import types
class someclass(object):
    val = "Value"
    def some_method(self):
        print self.val

def some_method_upper(self):
    print self.val.upper()

obj = someclass()
obj.some_method()

obj.some_method = types.MethodType(some_method_upper, obj)
obj.some_method()
```

Comment: Short of making a named inner class and instantiating it (which may be preferable for readability), option 3 seems like a good way to do this.

Comment: yes -- that's why I wrote "What you probably want". I just put it last because the post text flows better that way -- and I wanted to enumerate the options.

Comment: why are you using new? it is deprecated since quite a long time

Comment: since we are overwriting a previously defined method and the new temporarily named method (some_method_upper) is never used, why not use a lambda and make it inline since it will be more consistent with anonymous inline classes.

Comment: not sure but maybe something like: obj.some_method = types.MethodType(lambda self: print self.val.upper(), obj)

Comment: Of course -- in this trivial example, this can be done. The example merely demonstrates how to replace one method with another -- in a real-life example, a lambda might be suboptimal.

Comment: @fuentesjr: You can't use `print` in lambdas if Python version < 2.6

Answer (score 13):

Well, classes are first class objects, so you can create them in methods if you want.  e.g.

```
from optparse import OptionParser
def make_custom_op(i):
  class MyOP(OptionParser):
    def exit(self):
      print 'custom exit called', i
  return MyOP

custom_op_class = make_custom_op(3)
custom_op = custom_op_class()

custom_op.exit()          # prints 'custom exit called 3'
dir(custom_op)            # shows all the regular attributes of an OptionParser
```

But, really, why not just define the class at the normal level?  If you need to customise it, put the customisation in as arguments to `__init__`.

(edit: fixed typing errors in code)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand the line 

    custom_op = custom_op_class(). 

Should it be removed?

Comment: make_custom_op() returns a class.  You have to call the class to create an instance, which is what that line does.  However, there were a couple of bugs in my code on the last two lines, which I have now fixed, in case they were confusing you.

Comment: This is a simple but powerful technique that, when used properly (not just as a hack), can make for very elegant code.

Comment: so the answer is yes. To me this looks exactly like in java. Wrong am I ?

Answer (score 6):

Python doesn't support this directly (anonymous classes) but because of its terse syntax it isn't really necessary:

```
class MyOptionParser(OptionParser):
    def exit(self, status=0, msg=None):
        # body of method

p = MyOptionParser()
```

The only downside is you add MyOptionParser to your namespace, but as John Fouhy pointed out, you can hide that inside a function if you are going to do it multiple times.

Answer (score 5):

Python probably has better ways to solve your problem. If you could provide more specific details of what you want to do it would help.

For example, if you need to change the method being called in a specific point in code, you can do this by passing the function as a parameter (functions are first class objects in python, you can pass them to functions, etc). You can also create anonymous `lambda` functions (but they're restricted to a single expression).

Also, since python is very dynamic, you can change methods of an object after it's been created `object.method1 = alternative_impl1`, although it's actually a bit more complicated, see [gnud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357997/python-does-have-something-like-anonymous-inner-classes-of-java#358055)

Comment: You actually can't replace methods this way -- see my answer for the proper way.

Answer (score 2):

In python you have anonymous functions, declared using lambda statement. I do not like them very much - they are not so readable, and have limited functionality.

However, what you are talking about may be implemented in python with a completely different approach:

```
class a(object):
  def meth_a(self):
    print "a"

def meth_b(obj):
  print "b"

b = a()
b.__class__.meth_a = meth_b
```

Comment: Right track, but this does not work.   File "t", line 12, in <module>
    b.meth_a()
TypeError: meth_b() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: Right: to change a method of an object, you have to change it to its metaclass. I have updated the code.

Comment: b.__class__.meth_a = meth_b

Does this code affects all objects based on "a" class or only the "b" object?

Comment: Best to ask that as a separate question so the answers get votes

Comment: I think the question can be answered much better by simply playing at the interactive shell.
This is one of the major advantages for python: have a doubt or question on a language feature? ok play with it in the sjhell and see if it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can always hide class by variables:

```
 class var(...):
     pass
 var = var()
```

instead of

```
 var = new ...() {};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you would do in Python 3.7

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
class ExmapleClass:
    def exit(self):
        print('this should NOT print since we are going to override')

ExmapleClass= type('', (ExmapleClass,), {'exit': lambda self: print('you should see this printed only')})()
ExmapleClass.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this in python3 usually with inner classes

```py
class SomeSerializer():
    class __Paginator(Paginator):
        page_size = 10

    # defining it for e.g. Rest:
    pagination_class = __Paginator

    # you could also be accessing it to e.g. create an instance via method:
    def get_paginator(self):
        return self.__Paginator()
```

as i used double underscore, this mixes the idea of "mangling" with inner classes, from outside you can still access the inner class with `SomeSerializer._SomeSerializer__Paginator`, and also subclasses, but SomeSerializer.__Paginator will not work, which might or might not be your whish if you want it a bit more "anonymous".

However I suggest to use "private" notation with a single underscore, if you do not need the mangling.

In my case, all I need is a fast subclass to set some class attributes, followed up by assigning it to the class attribute of my RestSerializer class, so the double underscore would denote to "not use it at all further" and might change to no underscores, if I start reusing it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Being perverse, you could use the throwaway name `_` for the derived class name:

```
class _(OptionParser):

    def exit(self):
        pass  # your override impl
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more fancy way of doing Maciej's [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6175128/7420421).
I defined the following decorator:

```py
def newinstance(*args, **kwargs):
    def decorator(cls):
        return cls(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

The following codes are roughly equivalent (also works with args!)

```java
// java

MyClass obj = new MyClass(arg) {
    public void method() {
        // body of the method
    }
};
```

```py
# python

@newinstance(arg)
class obj(MyClass):
    def method(self):
        pass # body of the method
```

You can use this code from within a class/method/function if you want to define an "inner" class instance.