# Dynamically attaching a method to an existing Python object generated with swig?

Tags: python, class, dynamic, methods

I am working with a Python class, and I don't have write access to its declaration. 
How can I attach a custom method (such as **`__str__`**) to the objects created from that class without modifying the class declaration?

EDIT:
Thank you for all your answers. I tried them all but they haven't resolved my problem. Here is a minimal example that I hope will clarify the issue. I am using swig to wrap a C++ class, and the purpose is to override the `__str__` function of **an object** returned by the swig module. I use cmake to build the example:

**test.py**

```
import example

ex = example.generate_example(2)

def prnt(self):
    return str(self.x)

#How can I replace the __str__ function of object ex with prnt?
print ex
print prnt(ex)
```

**example.hpp**

```
struct example
{
    int x;
};

example generate_example(int x);
```

**example.cpp**

```
#include "example.hpp"
#include <iostream>

example generate_example(int x)
{
    example ex;
    ex.x = x;
    return ex;
}

int main()
{
    example ex = generate_example(2);
    std::cout << ex.x << "\n";
    return 1;
}
```

**example.i**

```
%module example

%{
#include "example.hpp"
%}

%include "example.hpp"
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

set_source_files_properties(example.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
swig_add_module(example python example.i example)
swig_link_libraries(example ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

if(APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_CREATE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_CREATE_CXX_FLAGS} -flat_namespace")
endif(APPLE)
```

To build and run test.py, copy all the files in a directory, and in that directory run

```
cmake .
make 
python test.py
```

This results in the following output:

```
<example.example; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'example *' at 0x10021cc40> >
2
```

As you can see the swig object has its own **str** function, and that is what I am trying to override.

Comment: Other StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you create a wrapper class, this will work with any other class, either built-in or not.  This is called "containment and delegation", and it is a common alternative to inheritance:

```
class SuperDuperWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, origobj):
        self.myobj = origobj
    def __str__(self):
        return "SUPER DUPER " + str(self.myobj)
    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        return getattr(self.myobj, attr)
```

The `__getattr__` method will delegate all undefined attribute requests on your SuperDuperWrapper object to the contained myobj object.  In fact, given Python's dynamic typing, you could use this class to SuperDuper'ly wrap just about anything:

```
s = "hey ho!"
sds = SuperDuperWrapper(s)
print sds

i = 100
sdi = SuperDuperWrapper(i)
print sdi
```

Prints:

```
SUPER DUPER hey ho!
SUPER DUPER 100
```

In your case, you would take the returned object from the function you cannot modify, and wrap it in your own SuperDuperWrapper, but you could still otherwise access it just as if it were the base object.

```
print sds.split()
['hey', 'ho!']
```

Comment: I used this technique very early in my Python career to write an interceptor for a proxy to a remote CORBA object - the client wanted one particular remote method to be slightly enhanced, but otherwise everything else was to behave the same.  Having only recently switched over from C++, I was aghast at how little code it took to write, as opposed to what C++ would have made me do.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the resulting wrapped object are not pickable, which sometimes is a big issue

Comment: Access is not _always_ as if it were the base object. For instance `isinstance(s, basestring == True`, but `isinstance(sds, basestring) == False`. Similarly, the `id()` and `type()` functions return different results.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> class C(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> def spam(self):
...     return 'spam'
... 
>>> C.__str__ = spam
>>> print C()
spam
```

It won't work on classes which use [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots).

Answer (score 3):

Create a subclass. Example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> datetime.datetime.__str__ = lambda self: 'spam'
...
TypeError: cant set attributes of built-in/extension type 'datetime.datetime'
>>> t.__str__ = lambda self: 'spam'
...
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object attribute '__str__' is read-only
>>> class mydate(datetime.datetime):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'spam'

>>> myt = mydate.now()
>>> print t
2009-09-05 13:11:34.600000
>>> print myt
spam
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my answer from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357997/does-python-have-something-like-anonymous-inner-classes-of-java/358055#358055):

```
import types
class someclass(object):
    val = "Value"
    def some_method(self):
        print self.val

def some_method_upper(self):
    print self.val.upper()

obj = someclass()
obj.some_method()

obj.some_method = types.MethodType(some_method_upper, obj)
obj.some_method()
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that using Alex's subclass idea, you can help yourself a little bit more using "`from` ... `import` ... `as`":

```
from datetime import datetime as datetime_original

class datetime(datetime_original):
   def __str__(self):
      return 'spam'
```

so now the class has the standard name, but different behaviour.

```
>>> print datetime.now()
    'spam'
```

Of course, this can be dangerous...

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I have an answer that no-one else had. There's a trick (which I found by accident) that allows you to append code to mapped clases.

In the SWIG file, add:

```
%extend example
{
    %pythoncode 
    %{
        def __repr__(self): ...
    %}
}
```

This works for classes, but it should also work on your case.

Comment: Thanks for contributing this, it's exactly what I was looking for. I had tried the `%pythoncode` bit without wrapping it in an `%extend`, but that just appended my custom Python code to the end of the SWIG-generated .py file, after SWIG registered my class with the .pyd. Extending the C++ class like this means SWIG puts the `%pythoncode` stuff directly into the SWIG Python class as if it was autogenerated.