# Completely wrap an object in Python

Tags: python, reflection

I am wanting to completely wrap an object so that all attribute and method requests get forwarded to the object it's wrapping, but also overriding any methods or variables that I want, as well as providing some of my own methods. This wrapper class should appear 100% as the existing class (`isinstance` must act as if it is actually the class), however subclassing in itself is not going to cut it, as I want to wrap an existing *object*. Is there some solution in Python to do this? I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
class ObjectWrapper(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, baseObject):
        self.baseObject = baseObject

    def overriddenMethod(self):
        ...

    def myOwnMethod1(self):
        ...

    ...

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in ['overriddenMethod', 'myOwnMethod1', 'myOwnMethod2', ...]
            # return the requested method
        else:
            return getattr(self.baseObject, attr)
```

But I'm not that familiar with overriding `__getattr__`, `__setattr__` and `__hasattr__`, so I'm not sure how to get that right.

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382871/dynamically-attaching-a-method-to-an-existing-python-object-generated-with-swig/1383646#1383646).

Answer (score 56):

The simplest way in most cases is probably:

```
class ObjectWrapper(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, baseObject):
        self.__class__ = type(baseObject.__class__.__name__,
                              (self.__class__, baseObject.__class__),
                              {})
        self.__dict__ = baseObject.__dict__

    def overriddenMethod(self):
        ...
```

Working in this way, i.e. by reassigning self's `__class__` and `__dict__` in this fashion, you need only provide your overrides -- Python's normal attribute getting and setting mechanisms will do the rest... *mostly*.

You'll be in trouble only if `baseObject.__class__` defines `__slots__`, in which case the multiple inheritance approach doesn't work and you do need the cumbersome `__getattr__` (as others said, at least you don't need to worry that it will be called with attributes you're overriding, as it won't!-), `__setattr__` (a greater pain, as it DOES get called for every attribute), etc; and making `isinstance` and special methods work takes painstaking and cumbersome detailed work.

Essentially, `__slots__` means that a class is a special, each instance a lightweight "value object" NOT to be subject to further sophisticated manipulation, wrapping, etc, because the need to save a few bytes per instance of that class overrides all the normal concerns about flexibility and so on; it's therefore not surprising that dealing with such extreme, rare classes in the same smooth and flexible way as you can deal with 99%+ of Python objects is truly a pain. So DO you need to deal with `__slots__` (to the point of writing, testing, debugging and maintaining hundreds of lines of code just for those corner cases), or will the 99% solution in half a dozen lines suffice?-)

It should also be noted that this may lead to memory leaks, as creating a subclass adds the subclass to the base class' list of subclasses, and isn't removed when all instances of the subclass are GC'd.

Comment: Could someone provide a link explaining this approach in more depth?  How do you know which __dict__ gets assigned first?  The one in the call to \_\_init\_\_? or the implicit one?

Comment: I find this approach too verbose and somewhat cryptic. What do you think about [my suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31437314/17523)?

Comment: @bgbg, your approach wraps a *class*, not an *object* as the OP requested.

Comment: I think `ObjectWrapper` deriving `BaseClass` is superfluous and moreover confusing!

Comment: The `__class__` should not be touched. Either way `isinstance(obj, BaseClass)` would return true because the wrapper object is an instance of a derived class.

Answer (score 12):

Please look at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577555-object-wrapper-class/ for the complete code, including important comments. It boils down to:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._wrapped_obj = obj
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in self.__dict__:
            return getattr(self, attr)
        return getattr(self._wrapped_obj, attr)
```

Comment: This is a good approach, you just don't have to check if the attr is in the dict. `__getattr__` is called only if the atribute is not in the dict.

Comment: There is a subtle issue with this in that if ```__getattr__``` does not raise an AttributeError  for attributes that don't exist then hasattr will return True, and some other code may try to access that. So hasattr(Wrapper({}), 'foo') will be true when that's clearly not what you want.

Comment: You should add the lines `def __setattr__(self, name, value):` and `setattr(self._wrapped_obj, name, value)`, and change the `__init__` to `self.__dict__['_wrapped_obj'] = obj` to [prevent recursive calling of `__setattr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12999019).

Comment: I have found that if I use this approach I don't seem to be able to pickle/unpickle the wrapped object, it causes a RecursionError when unpicking. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

`__getattr__` has the advantage that it's only called when the attribute does not exist, so you should not need an explicit list -- anything you don't define will automatically get proxied.

`__setattr__` is trickier because it's always called. Make sure you use a superclass call or `object.__setattr__` when setting your own attributes; using `setattr()` within `__setattr__` will cause infinite recursion.

The final bit, affecting isinstance, is very difficult. You can do it with an assigment to your wrapper instance's .`__class__` variable (but this also overrides class dictionary resolution order), or by dynamically constructing your wrapper type using a metaclass. Since isinstance is so rare in Python code, it seems overkill to actually try to trick it.

[More information on special attribute access methods.](http://python.org/doc/2.2/ref/attribute-access.html)

[Even more information on them, plus some help with metaclasses.](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation)

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* This answer is really old and might not work on modern Pythons. I believe it used to work on 2.6

Start with this and mess with stuff in the loop to suit your needs:

```
import inspect
class Delegate(object):
    def __init__(self, implementation):
        self.__class__ = implementation.__class__
        for n, m in inspect.getmembers(implementation, callable):
            if not n.startswith('_'):
                setattr(self, n, m)
```

The ability to wrap not-new-style-objects is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: This failed when I tried it:  `self.__class__ = implementation.__class__
TypeError: __class__ assignment only supported for heap types or ModuleType subclasses`

Comment: Considering that response is 9 old, chances are the Python internals have changed since...Python 2.6? :)

Answer (score 0):

By 'existing object' you mean an instance of another class? Sounds to me as though you just need to inherit from the base class. When you create your new object, pass in the details of the base object, or add a method in your new class which copies the data of the base class instance into itself.

Comment: If only it were that simple. The class I'm wrapping is a third-party one, and I believe it's written in C. Makes it a whole heap harder (and it could change when we update to a new version of the third-party library, and I'd rather not then have to change our code too.)

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case.. so basically you want to create an interface to an existing class. In which case, your suggestion is probably a neat way of going about it. Good luck :-)

Answer (score -1):

The following approach is similar to [the one by Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445289/17523), but is more readable to me:

Instead of creating a new class, I create a class-like function that instantiates the underlying object and overwrites needed functions, as follows:

```
class C1:
    def __init__(self, p):
        self.p = p
    def f(self):
        print("This is C1, p=%s" % self.p)

def C2(p):
    c = C1(p)
    def new_f():
        print("This is C2, p is %s" % c.p)
    c.f = new_f
    def g(param):
        print("This is C2.g(%s), p is %s" % (param, c.p))
    c.g = g
    return c

c1 = C1('abc')
c1.f()

c2 = C2('cde')
c2.f()
c2.g('xyz')
```

The output:

```
This is C1, p=abc

This is C2, p is cde
This is C2.g(xyz), p is cde
```

Comment: This does not really answer the OP's question: With this approach one cannot wrap an object (an existing instance of a class). Only the class is wrapped.