# Clean way to disable `__setattr__` until after initialization

Tags: python, python-3.x, setattr

I've written the following wrapper class. I want to define `__setattr__` such that it redirects all attributes to the wrapped class. However, this prevents me from initializing the wrapper class. Any elegant way to fix this?

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, value):
        # How to use the default '__setattr__' inside '__init__'?
        self.value = value

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        setattr(self.value, name, value)
```

Comment: What does `Wrapper` wrap? Why doesn't it inherit `object`?

Comment: @Tichodroma It wraps anything. I'm using it in a GUI application; the wrapper notifies listeners when the enclosed object is modified. It doesn't inherit from `object` because I only want to use Python 3.

Comment: This technique ("OOP pattern") is known as [Delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) (or, more precisely, [Forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forwarding_(object-oriented_programming)#Delegation)).
[Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-is-delegation) has an example usage, and a note about taking care when implementing `__setattr__()`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are catching all assignments, which prevents the constructor from assigning `self.value`. You can use `self.__dict__` to access the instance dictionary. Try:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.__dict__['value'] = value

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        setattr(self.value, name, value)
```

Another way using `object.__setattr__`:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'value', value)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        setattr(self.value, name, value)
```

Comment: Nice. One question though: why should I use `self.__dict__['value']` inside `__setattr__` as well?

Comment: @Paul Sorry, you don't need that. I thought you were overriding `__getattr__` as well.

Answer (score 11):

A way to disable the `__setattr__` until after initialization without changing the `self.value = value` syntax in the `__init__` method is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16426447). In short, embed knowledge of initialization in the object and use it in the `__setattr__` method. For your `Wrapper`:

```
class Wrapper:
    __initialized = False
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.__initialized = True

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if self.__initialized:
            # your __setattr__ implementation here
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `__getattr__` overridden as well::

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self,wrapped):
        self.__dict__['wrapped'] = wrapped
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        setattr(self.__dict__['wrapped'],name,value)
    def __getattr__(self,name):
        return getattr(self.__dict__['wrapped'],name)


class A:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

wa = Wrapper(A(3))
#wa.a == wa.wrapped.a == 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in other answers, one idea is to directly access the object dictionary to bypass `setattr` resolution.

For something easy to read, I suggest the following:

```
  def __init__(self,wrapped1, wrapped2):
       vars(self).update(dict(
          _wrapped1=wrapped1,
          _wrapped2=wrapped2,
        ))
```

Using [vars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) is optional, but I find it nicer than directly accessing `self.__dict__`, and the inline `dict()` notation allows for grouping all instance variable initialization in a visible block with minimum boilerplate code overhead.