# Overriding __setattr__ at runtime

Tags: python

I am trying to override the `__setattr__` method of a Python class, since I want to call another function each time an instance attribute changes its value. However, I don't want this behaviour in the `__init__` method, because during this initialization I set some attributes which are going to be used later:

So far I have this solution, without overriding `__setattr__` at runtime:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, host):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'a', a)
        object.__setattr__(self, 'b', b)
        result = self.process(a)
        for key, value in result.items():
            object.__setattr__(self, key, value)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print(self.b) # Call to a function using self.b
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

However, I would like to avoid these `object.__setattr__(...)` and override `__setattr__` at the end of the `__init__` method:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        result = self.process(a)
        for key, value in result.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
        # override self.__setattr__ here

    def aux(self, name, value):
        print(self.b)
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

I have tried with `self.__dict__['__setitem__'] = self.aux` and `object.__setitem__['__setitem__'] = self.aux`, but none of these attemps has effect. I have read [this section of the data model reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__), but it looks like the assignment of the own `__setattr__` is a bit tricky.

How could be possible to override `__setattr__` at the end of `__init__`, or at least have a pythonic solution where `__setattr__` is called in the normal way only in the constructor?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to "override, after init" python special methods; as a side effect of how that lookup works.  The crux of the problem is that python doesn't actually look at the instance; except to get its class; before it starts looking up the special method; so there's no way to get the object's state to affect which method is looked up.

If you don't like the special behavior in `__init__`, you could refactor your code to put the special knowledge in `__setattr__` instead.  Something like:

```
class Foo(object):
    __initialized = False
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        try:
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
            # ...
        finally:
            self.__initialized = True

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if self.__initialzed:
            print(self.b)
        super(Foo, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
```

Edit:  Actually, there is a way to change which special method is looked up, so long as you *change its class* after it has been initialized.  This approach will send you far into the weeds of metaclasses, so without further explanation, here's how that looks:

```
class AssignableSetattr(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs):
        def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
            object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)

        init_attrs = dict(attrs)
        init_attrs['__setattr__'] = __setattr__

        init_cls = super(AssignableSetattr, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, init_attrs)

        real_cls = super(AssignableSetattr, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, (init_cls,), attrs)
        init_cls.__real_cls = real_cls

        return init_cls

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = super(AssignableSetattr, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        print "Created", self
        real_cls = cls.__real_cls
        self.__class__ = real_cls
        return self


class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = AssignableSetattr

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        for key, value in process(a).items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        frob(self.b)
        super(Foo, self).__setattr__(attr, value)


def process(a):
    print "processing"
    return {'c': 3 * a}


def frob(x):
    print "frobbing", x


myfoo = Foo(1, 2)
myfoo.d = myfoo.c + 1
```

Comment: Wow!!! Just wow. I stumbled upon this and almost dismissed it, but as it turns out it is exactly what I need to solve a similar problem. Some serious Python magic in this answer. Sorry I can't upvote 100 times :p

Answer (score 6):

@SingleNegationElimination's answer is great, but it cannot work with inheritence, since the child class's `__mro__` store's the original class of super class. Inspired by his answer, with little change,

The idea is simple, switch `__setattr__` before `__init__`, and restore it back after `__init__` completed.

```
class CleanSetAttrMeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        real_setattr = cls.__setattr__
        cls.__setattr__ = object.__setattr__
        self = super(CleanSetAttrMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.__setattr__ = real_setattr
        return self


class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = CleanSetAttrMeta

    def __init__(self):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        print 'after __init__', self.b
        super(Foo, self).__setattr__(key, value)


class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
        self.c = 3

>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.a = 10
after __init__ 2
>>>
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.c = 30
after __init__ 2
```