# write protect class scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Background**

I have a task executioner framework that allows people to write code like this.

```
class HandleJob(Job):

  @Step()
  def do_work(self, work_order):
    pass

  @Step()
  def continue_with_doing_work(self, work_order):
    pass
```

The framework calls the steps in a defined order and pass along the work order. The important thing to know though is that the different `Step`s can be called by different instances of `HandleJob`, or rather during different executions of the script. This means that a developer *CANNOT* write stuff to `self` in one `Step` and expect it to be available in another `Step`.

There is a dedicated place to store data needed later and documentation is clear about this. However, I still want to be able to enforce 'fail early'.

**Question (TLDR)**

Is there some way I can lock down the scope preventing developers from writing variables to `self` during runtime.

To complicate things further. They should be able to write to `self` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution ([Overriding __setattr__ at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426141/overriding-setattr-at-runtime)).

```
class Job:

    _scope_locked = False

    def __init__(self, work_order_id, strict=True):
        if strict:
            self._scope_locked = True

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if self._scope_locked:
            raise Exception("'self' locked")
        else:
            super(Job, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
```

The only issue with this solution is that super needs to be called last in the child class constructor. Oh well.

Comment: To provide a simpler API to the user (without having to remember where to call super-init), you might have `__init__` call `do_init` or something like that at the right place, to be implemeted by the sub-classes.