# Python: standard function and context manager?

Tags: python, contextmanager

In python, there are many functions that work as both standard functions and context managers. For example `open()` can be called either as:

```
my_file=open(filename,'w')
```

or

```
with open(filename,'w') as my_file:
```

Both giving you a `my_file` object that can be used to do whatever you need to. In general the later is preferable, but there are times when one might want to do the former as well.

I've been able to figure out how to write a context manager, either by creating a class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions or by using the `@contextlib.contextmanager` decorator on a function and `yield` rather than `return`. However, when I do this I can no longer use the function straight - using the decorator, for example, I get a `_GeneratorContextManager` object back rather than the result that wanted. Of course, if I made it as a class, I'd just get an instance of the generator class, which I'd assume is essentially the same thing.

So how can I design a function (or class) that works as either a function, returning an object, or a context manager, returning a `_GeneratorContextManager` or the like?

edit:

For example, say I have a function like the following (this is HIGHLY simplified):

```
def my_func(arg_1,arg_2):
    result=arg_1+arg_2
    return my_class(result)
```

So the function takes a number of arguments, does stuff with them, and uses the result of that stuff to initialize a class, which it then returns. End result is I have an instance of `my_class`, just like I would have a `file` object if I had called `open`. If I want to be able to use this function as a context manager, I can modify it like so:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def my_func(arg_1,arg_2):
    result=arg_1+arg_2 # This is roughly equivalent to the __enter__ function
    yield my_class(result)
    <do some other stuff here> # This is roughly equivalent to the __exit__function
```

Which works just fine when calling as a context manager, but I no longer get an instance of `my_class` when calling as a straight function. Perhaps I'm just doing something wrong?

Edit 2:

Note that I do have full control over `my_class`, including the ability to add functions to it. From the accepted answer below, I was able to infer that my difficulty stemmed from a basic misunderstanding: I was thinking that whatever I called (`my_func` in the example above) needed to have the `__exit__` and `__enter__` functions. This is not correct. In fact, it's only what the function *returns* (`my_class` in the above example) that needs the functions in order to work as a context manager.

Comment: `open` is a function that returns an instance of a class.  Whether you use `myfile = open(filename)` or `with open(filename) as myfile`, it will still be an instance of the same class.  Nothing is changed.

Comment: @zondo True, as is the function I am trying to write. However, when I wrap the function in the `@contextlib.contextmanager` decorator, and call it as a standard function, the class I get back is NOT the class I "yield" from the function. Only when I call it as a context manager do I get that class. I'll add a simple example.

Comment: Define a `__call__` method in your class.

Comment: @apex-meme-lord: So I would write the context manager class with a `__call__` method, which returns the instantiated class I want? Does the fact I don't explicitly have an `__init__ ` method mean that `__call__` will be used instead when I do something like `my_instance=cm_class(a,b)`? My understanding is that `__call__` is used when calling an instance, and I don't have an instance (yet).

Comment: Adding `__call__` is not what you want. That will let you use `x = my_func(); x()`, but that doesn't help in this case.

Comment: @DavidWolever You are correct, but the initialized object is exactly what was requested.  `x` will work as both a callable function and a context manager.

Comment: @apex-meme-lord can you give an example? The desired behavior is being able to use either `x = my_func(); x.my_method()` or `with my_func() as x: x.my_method()` and it's not clear how `__call__` would make that possible.

Comment: @apex-meme-lord No, I do not have an initialized object. The function call *returns* an initialized object, but I do not have one at the point I want to call the function/use it as a context manager. What David Wolever said is spot-on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difficulty you're going to run into is that for a function to be used as both a context manager (`with foo() as x`) and a regular function (`x = foo()`), the object returned from the function needs to have both `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods… and there isn't a great way — in the general case — to add methods to an existing object.

One approach might be to create a wrapper class that uses `__getattr__` to pass methods and attributes to the original object:

```
class ContextWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.__obj = obj

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        ... handle __exit__ ...

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.__obj, attr)
```

But this will cause subtle issues because it isn't *exactly* the same as the object that was returned by the original function (ex, `isinstance` tests will fail, some builtins like `iter(obj)` won't work as expected, etc).

You could also dynamically subclass the returned object as demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445289/71522:

```
class ObjectWrapper(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.__class__ = type(
            obj.__class__.__name__,
            (self.__class__, obj.__class__),
            {},
        )
        self.__dict__ = obj.__dict__

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        ... handle __exit__ ...
```

But this approach has issues too (as noted in the linked post), and it's a level of magic I personally wouldn't be comfortable introducing without *strong* justification.

I generally prefer either adding explicit `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, or using a helper like [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing):

```
with closing(my_func()) as my_obj:
    … do stuff …
```

Comment: Ah, the key I was missing was that the object *returned* needed the `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions - not necessarily the object (function in this case) *called*. So by adding those functions to the class returned by the function, with the `__enter__` function simply returning `self`, it works!

Answer (score 6):

Just for clarity: if you are able to change `my_class`, you would of course add the `__enter__/__exit__` descriptors to that class.

If you are not able to change `my_class` (which I inferred from your question), this is the solution I was referring to:

```
class my_class(object):

    def __init__(self, result):
        print("this works", result)

class manage_me(object):

    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, ex_typ, ex_val, traceback):
        return True

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.callback(*args, **kwargs)


def my_func(arg_1,arg_2):
    result=arg_1+arg_2
    return my_class(result)


my_func_object = manage_me(my_func) 

my_func_object(1, 1)
with my_func_object as mf:
    mf(1, 2)
```

---

As a decorator:

```
@manage_me
def my_decorated_func(arg_1, arg_2):
    result = arg_1 + arg_2
    return my_class(result)

my_decorated_func(1, 3)
with my_decorated_func as mf:
    mf(1, 4)
```

Comment: I'm quite able to change my_class. My confusion stemmed from the fact that I'm not calling (or instantiating) my_class directly - rather, I call a function that returns an instance of my_class, and I wanted to be able to use that function either as a function or as a context manager - just like you can with the open() function. I didn't realize that it was the *returned* object that needed to behave as a context manager - I thought the function I was *calling* needed to be a context manager.