# Wrapping an object completely without knowing anything about it (python)

Tags: python, wrapper, condor

I am working with `htcondor` python bindings (https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/python-bindings/index.html)

You don't need to know htcondor, but for reference I am working with the
[htcondor.JobEvent](https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/python-bindings/api/htcondor.html#htcondor.JobEvent) class to get the data that I want.
From the description of that object it follows that it behaves like a dictionary,
but it has no `__dict__` property.

Basically you **can't** tell what this object is, because it's translated from C++ into python, hence I want to wrap it with all it's functionalities to add more functionalities.

The way I am solving this atm is:

```
class HTCJobEventWrapper:
    """
    Wrapper for HTCondor JobEvent.

    Extracts event number and time_stamp of an event.
    The wrapped event can be printed to the terminal for dev purpose.

    :param job_event: HTCJobEvent
    """

    def __init__(self, job_event: HTCJobEvent):
        self.wrapped_class = job_event
        self.event_number = job_event.get('EventTypeNumber')
        self.time_stamp = date_time.strptime(
                job_event.get('EventTime'),
                STRP_FORMAT
            )

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.wrapped_class, attr)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Wraps wrapped_class get function."""
        return self.wrapped_class.get(*args, **kwargs)

    def items(self):
        """Wraps wrapped_class items method."""
        return self.wrapped_class.items()

    def keys(self):
        """Wraps wrapped_class keys method."""
        return self.wrapped_class.keys()

    def values(self):
        """Wraps wrapped_class values method."""
        return self.wrapped_class.values()

    def to_dict(self):
        """Turns wrapped_class items into a dictionary."""
        return dict(self.items())

    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps(
            self.to_dict(),
            indent=2
        )
```

With this it's possible to get any attribute and to use the methods described in the documentation.

However as you can see `HTCJobEventWrapper` is not of type `htcondor.JobEvent`
and is not inheriting from it.
If you try to instatiate a `htcondor.JobEvent` class it results in the following error: `RuntimeError: This class cannot be instantiated from Python`.

What I want:
I would like it to be a child class which copies a given `htcondor.JobEvent` object *completely*
and adds the functionalities I want and returns a `HTCJobEventWrapper` object

This kind of relates to this question: [completely wrap an object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443129/completely-wrap-an-object-in-python)

Is there a pythonic way to dynamically call every attribute, function or method on `self.wrapped_class` ? Just like with `getattr` ?
But in this case I've tried `getattr` but it works only for attributes.

Comment: Why can't you simply subclass `HTCJobEventWrapper`, override the methods you like and use `super()` as needed? If you inherit from `HTCJobEventWrapper` then objects of this new type *are* considered to be `HTCJobEventWrapper` objects (in the sense that `isinstance(obj, HTCJobEventWrapper)` returns `True`).

Comment: I can't cause I don't know how to initialize this htcondor.JobEvent, i really don't know nothing about it. That's the point here.

Comment: The `__init__` method ships with `HTCJobEventWrapper` so you don't need to know its details.

Comment: A I see but this only answers my question partly. What if I have an existing `htcondor.JobEvent` object that I want to turn into a HTCJobEventWrapper ?
Consider that I would like to dynamically call any attribute or method on the original wrapped object.

Comment: I have tried this: 
I get the following result: `RuntimeError: This class cannot be instantiated from Python
`

Comment: Can you clarify why it is relevant that your wrapper *is a* ``htcondor.JobEvent``? You cannot *completely* wrap an object and even a child class is not a complete replacement for the parent. What does the wrapper have to provide in practice?

Comment: @Krotonix So you want a wrapper object like the one you created *and* make it behave as if `isinstance(obj, HTCJobEventWrapper)`?