# Python (3.10) Extending existing object interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dynamic, interface

Was looking around for "clean" approach (supposedly, given the need) for "Wrapping up **existing** object by implicitly (without inheritance) **extending** the interface".

Rationale:

1. No changes to be done tp Core classes (considered to be constructed as part of some framework)
2. "Transparent extension" - once the Core object garbage-collected by the framework it cant be used (weak-ref)
3. The exposed interface should consists out of **Core** and **Extended (by the new class)** attributes and methods

So stumbled upon several solutions where the most close one was the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443129/completely-wrap-an-object-in-python)
Although it is address the requirements (most of them) I've still had issue with it.
for instance,

- not calling super in __init__ raises PEP8 warning (I guess it can be suppressed but still..)
- no weak-ref, if framework decides to end the object, the extension class wouldn't be aware of it

so tried following approach below where __call__ of the meta-class returns union of the **Core** and **Extension class** (for interface hinting to the user) along with **Extension** functionalities while storing weak-ref to the original **Core** object and fallback to him whenever attribute is missing.

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar, Generic


class CoreBase:
    def __init__(self, core_base_arg):
        print("In CoreBase INIT")
        self.core_base_arg = core_base_arg

    def core_base_a(self):
        print(f"[{type(self)}] in CORE BASE (method: core base A) (arg: {self.core_base_arg})")


class Core(CoreBase):
    def __init__(self, core_arg, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("In Core INIT")
        self._core_arg = core_arg

    def core_a(self):
        print(f"[{type(self)}] in CORE (method: core A) (arg: {self._core_arg})")

    def core_b(self):
        print(f"[{type(self)}] in CORE (method: core B) (arg: {self._core_arg})")


_Extend_From_Type = TypeVar('_Extend_From_Type')
_Extend_To_Type = TypeVar('_Extend_To_Type')


class InstanceWeakRefExtenderMeta(type, Generic[_Extend_From_Type, _Extend_To_Type]):

    # [Needs to be defined for type-hinting]
    def __call__(cls: Type[_Extend_From_Type], core_obj: _Extend_To_Type, *args, **kwargs) \
            -> _Extend_From_Type | _Extend_To_Type:
        extending_core_obj = super(InstanceWeakRefExtenderMeta, cls).__call__(core_obj, *args, **kwargs)
        extending_core_obj._core_weak_ref = weakref.ref(core_obj)
        return extending_core_obj


class ExtendedExistingCoreObject(metaclass=InstanceWeakRefExtenderMeta):

    #        ...(self, core_obj: Core, additional_core_extension_args, *args, **kwargs)
    def __init__(self, _: Core, additional_core_extension_args, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._additional_core_extension_args = additional_core_extension_args

    def extended_core_object_method(self):
        print(f"[{type(self)}] In extended core object method, "
              f"additional_core_extension_args={self._additional_core_extension_args}")

    def core_b(self):
        print(f"[{type(self)}] In extended core object method, Overriden core_b method")

    # Fallback to extended object in case of missing attribute
    def __getattr__(self, attr_to_get):
        return getattr(self._core_weak_ref(), attr_to_get)


print("Extending existing Core instance, Defining new meta-class with unite type-hint")
_core_object = Core("core_arg", "core_base_arg")
...
extended_core_object = ExtendedExistingCoreObject(_core_object, "core_extension_arg")
extended_core_object.core_base_a()
extended_core_object.core_a()
extended_core_object.extended_core_object_method()
extended_core_object.core_b()
```

**Executing it does pretty much what intended to do but im curious whether I've missed any thing ?**

> Extending existing Core instance, Attempt 3 - Defining new meta-class with unite type-hint
> In CoreBase INIT
> In Core INIT
> [<class '**main**.Core'>] in CORE BASE (method: core base A) (arg: core_base_arg)
> [<class '**main**.Core'>] in CORE (method: core A) (arg: core_arg)
> [<class '**main**.ExtendedExistingCoreObject'>] In extended core object method, additional_core_extension_args=core_extension_arg
> [<class '**main**.ExtendedExistingCoreObject'>] In extended core object method, Overriden core_b method