# Using standard tensorflow layers in a 'cell'-like manner

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, language-features

My question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430601/mixing-feed-forward-layers-and-recurrent-layers-in-tensorflow)*.

Is it possible to transform standard tensorflow layers into 'cells', to be used together with [RNN cells](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.8/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/RNNCell) to compose recurrent neural networks?

So, the new 'cell' should store the parameters (weights, ...), and be able to be called on **varying inputs**. Something like this:

```
from tf.nn import batch_normalization, conv2d
from tf.contrib.rnn import MultiRNNCell, LSTMCell

bn_cell = cell_creation_fun(batch_normalization, otherparams) # batch norm cell
conv_cell = cell_creation_fun(conv2d, otherparams )           # non-rnn conv cell
# or `conv_cell = cell_creation_fun(tf.layers.Conv2D, otherparams )` # using tf.layers
```

So that they can be used like this:

```
multi_cell = MultiRNNCell([LSTMCell(...), conv_cell, bn_cell])
```

Or like this:

```
h = ...
conv_h, _ = conv_cell(h, state=None)
normed_h, _ = bn_cell(h, state=None)
```

---

The only thing I could think of is manually writing such a 'cell' for every layer I want to use, subclassing [RNNCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.8/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/RNNCell). But it doesn't seem straightforward to use existing functions like Conv2D without being able to pass an ´input´ parameter during creation. (Will post code when I manage.)

---

* Maybe asking in a more targeted way has a chance of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I have so far:

```
class LayerCell(rnn_cell_impl.RNNCell):

    def __init__(self, tf_layer, **kwargs):
        ''' :param tf_layer: a tensorflow layer, e.g. tf.layers.Conv2D or 
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D. NOT tf.layers.conv2d !'''
        self.layer_fn = tf_layer(**kwargs)

    def __call__(self, inputs, state, scope=None):
        ''' Every `RNNCell` must implement `call` with
          the signature `(output, next_state) = call(input, state)`.  The optional
          third input argument, `scope`, is allowed for backwards compatibility
          purposes; but should be left off for new subclasses.'''
        return (self.layer_fn(inputs), state)

    def __str__(self):
            return "Cell wrapper of " + str(self.layer_fn)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        '''credits to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382871/dynamically-attaching-a-method-to-an-existing-python-object-generated-with-swig/1383646#1383646'''
        return getattr(self.layer_fn, attr)

    @property
    def state_size(self):
        """size(s) of state(s) used by this cell.

        It can be represented by an Integer, a TensorShape or a tuple of Integers
        or TensorShapes.
        """
        return  (0,) 

    @property
    def output_size(self):
        """Integer or TensorShape: size of outputs produced by this cell."""
        # use with caution; could be uninitialized
        return self.layer_fn.output_shape
```

---

(Naturally, don't use with recurrent layers because state-keeping will be destroyed.)

Seems to work with: tf.layers.Conv2D, tf.keras.layers.Conv2D, tf.keras.layers.Activation, tf.layers.BatchNormalization

*Does NOT work with: tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization.*
At least it failed for me when using it in a tf.while loop;  complaining about combining variables from different frames, similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564698/invalidargumenterror-the-node-has-inputs-from-different-frames). Maybe keras uses [tf.Variable() instead of tf.get_variable()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8604) ...?

---

Usuage:

```
cell0 = tf.contrib.rnn.ConvLSTMCell(conv_ndims=2, input_shape=[40, 40, 3], output_channels=16, kernel_shape=[5, 5])
cell1 = LayerCell(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D, filters=8, kernel_size=[5, 5], strides=(1, 1), padding='same')
cell2 = LayerCell(tf.layers.BatchNormalization, axis=-1)

inputs =  np.random.rand(10, 40, 40, 3).astype(np.float32)
multicell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell0, cell1, cell2])
state = multicell.zero_state(batch_size=10, dtype=tf.float32)

output = multicell(inputs, state)
print("Yippee!")
```